# Is there a clean relation between the Tricomi function $U(-a,b,z)$ (as a function of its first argument) and an Airy function?

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function, airy-functions

Following a suggestion from [this thread on Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/33367/robust-ways-to-find-zeros-of-the-tricomi-confluent-hypergeometric-function-as-a), I had a brief look at a plot of 
$$
f(E) = \frac{U(-E,1,R)}{\Gamma(1+E)},
$$
i.e. the Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function as a function of its first parameter, which looks like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

for $R=10$. I'm struck by the resemblance to an Airy function, but I can't find any clean results relating the two. Are any such links known?

Comment: It does look a lot like $-\mathrm{Ai}(x)$. Have you considered the relation $$\mathrm{Ai}(x)=\frac{1}{3^{2/3}\Gamma(\frac23)}\,_0F_1(;\tfrac23;\tfrac{x^3}{9})-\frac{x}{3^{1/3}\Gamma(\frac13)}\,_0F_1(;\tfrac43;\tfrac{x^3}{9})?$$ It may not result in anything useful, but there is sort of a resemblance to $$U(a,b,x)=\frac{\Gamma(1-b)}{\Gamma(a+1-b)}M(a,b,x)+\frac{\Gamma(b-1)}{\Gamma(a)}M(a+1-b,2-b,x),$$ where $$M(a,b,x)=\,_1F_1(a;b;x).$$